# multiheader pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, hdf5

Is it possible to replicate the structure of this csv using a `pandas.DataFrame`?

[image]

All the data is being pulled from one `HDF5` file and then parsing out the attributes to the `pd.DataFrame`

**My concerns** are that the `meta header` and `meta data` (lines 1 and 2 in the csv) do no match the `attribute header` and `attribute data` length or shape.

Here is how I called the `pd.DataFrame`:

```
    # Meta Pandas DataFrame
    meta_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0, 8760, 24), columns=['source', 'location_id', 'state', 'country', 'latitude', 
                                                              'longitude', 'time_zone', 'elevation', 'clearsky_dhi', 
                                                              'clearsky_dni', 'clearsky_ghi', 'dewpoint_unit', 
                                                              'temperature_unit'])
    # Meta Header & Data
    meta_df['source'] = source
    meta_df['location_id'] = location_id
    meta_df['state'] = state
    meta_df['country'] = country
    meta_df['latitude'] = latitude
    meta_df['longitude'] = longitude
    meta_df['time_zone'] = local_time
    meta_df['elevation'] = elevation
    meta_df['clearsky_dhi'] = clearsky_dhi
    meta_df['clearsky_dni'] = clearsky_dni
    meta_df['clearsky_ghi'] = clearsky_ghi
    meta_df['dewpoint_unit'] = dewpoint_unit
    meta_df['temperature_unit'] = temperature_unit

    # Attribute Pandas DataFrame
    att_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0, 8760, 24), columns=['dhi', 'dni', 'ghi', 'source', 'dew_point', 'temperature'])

    # Attribute Header & Data
    att_df['year'] = year
    att_df['month'] = month
    att_df['day'] = day
    att_df['hour'] = hour
    att_df['minute'] = minute
    att_df['dhi'] = dhi
    att_df['dni'] = dni
    att_df['ghi'] = ghi
    att_df['dew_point'] = dew_point
    att_df['temperature'] = temperature

    # Make one DataFrame with multiple headers?
    # Do something, then export to csv.
    df.to_csv(ndir_root + ndir + '/' + fname + '.csv', index=False)
```

Is it be best to create two seperate dataframes and then stack them vertically to create a third dataframe and export the final one as a csv?

bueller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this via .to_csv() since this method accepts either a file path (as you have done) or a buffer.  I assume you know the order of your meta header, meta data, and attribute header strings, so you can choose how you write those out to file.  The piece you are missing is represented below.

```
with open('output.csv','w') as fid:
    # write your meta header etc., here assumed to be a list of strings
    fid.write(','.join(meta_header) + '\n')
    fid.write(','.join(meta_data) + '\n')
    fid.write(','.join(attribute_header) + '\n')

    # now write attr_df to a csv by passing data to your fid buffer
    attr_df.to_csv(fid, sep=',', header=False, index=False)
```